# MVC 5 with Angular 11 hot reloading

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-mvc-5, angular11, webpack-hmr

I'm trying to setup hot reloading for an ASP.NET MVC 5 application along with Angular 11.

What I have already achieved:

1. I'm referring to application bundles in `Index.cshtml` like this:

[image]

2. I'm hosting Angular 11 application like this:

   ```
    ng serve --public-host=https://localhost:4200 --ssl --hmr
   ```

After I serve the Angular app and run the ASP.NET MVC project, it loads the application nicely. However there is only **Live Reloading** enabled, not **HMR**.

I know that HMR is running fine since when I open Angular app at localhost:4200, it maintains input value after updating some text on landing page:

[image]

However on the ASP.NET MVC page that is using bundles, whole page is reloaded after bundles change, but state is not maintained...

**What I need**: I need the ASP.NET MVC page too keep the state after bundle changes. To not have just **Live Reloading**, but **Hot Module Reloading**

Does anyone know what am I missing in the setup to enable HMR?